# RecyclerView not updating on Fragment - Adapter shows null on notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I am trying to implement a sales app with 3 stages, whereby a user first adds the items, views the cart to checkout and prints a receipt. The first stage is done and works well. I am implementing this using one Activity with a tabbed layout and 3 fragments for each of the tabs.

On the activity for viewing the cart, I am using a RecyclerView which loads well when the activity is created, but once I add an item and try to view the list, there is no update. However, when I print the item list, the item has been added.

I have tried to update the RecyclerView using `notifyDataSetChanged()` but it gives me a null pointer exception. I have and tried several solutions but none has worked. Kindly assist.

Below is my code.

`NewSaleActivity.java`

```
public class NewSaleActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    private ActivityNewSaleBinding binding;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    Context context;
    ViewPager viewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityNewSaleBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.new_sale_toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.new_sale);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.new_sale_drawer);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.new_sale_navigation);
        navigationView.bringToFront();

        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_sale);

        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        toggle.syncState();

        context = getApplicationContext();

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);

        SectionsPagerAdapter sectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(this, getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = binding.viewPager;
        viewPager.setAdapter(sectionsPagerAdapter);
        viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        TabLayout tabs = binding.tabLayout;
        tabs.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                //When cart tab is selected
                if(tab.getPosition() == 1) {
                    CartFragment cartFragment = new CartFragment();
                    cartFragment.loadItemsInCart();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_home:
                Intent mainIntent = new Intent(NewSaleActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(mainIntent);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_inventory:
                Intent inventoryIntent = new Intent(NewSaleActivity.this, InventoryActivity.class);
                startActivity(inventoryIntent);
                finish();
                break;

            case R.id.nav_sale:
                break;

            case R.id.nav_logout:
                UserLogout.userLogout(NewSaleActivity.this);
                break;
        }

        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
}
```

`CartFragment.java`

```
public class CartFragment extends Fragment {
RecyclerView cartRecyclerView;
TextInputLayout grossTotalInput, discountInput, netTotalInput;
Button checkoutButton;
CartItemAdapter cartItemAdapter;
ArrayList<CartItem> cartItemList;

public CartFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static CartFragment newInstance() {
    CartFragment fragment = new CartFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    cartRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.cart_recycler_view);
    grossTotalInput = view.findViewById(R.id.gross_total_input);
    discountInput = view.findViewById(R.id.discount_input);
    netTotalInput = view.findViewById(R.id.net_total_input);
    checkoutButton = view.findViewById(R.id.checkout_button);

    Paper.init(requireContext());

    cartItemList = Paper.book().read("cartItems", new ArrayList<CartItem>());
    cartRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    cartItemAdapter = new CartItemAdapter(cartItemList);
    cartRecyclerView.setAdapter(cartItemAdapter);

    checkoutButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            checkoutOrder();
        }
    });

    cartItemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cart, container, false);
}

public void loadItemsInCart() {
    ArrayList<CartItem> cartList = Paper.book().read("cartItems", new ArrayList<CartItem>());
    for(CartItem cartItem : cartList) {
        Log.d("cartItem", cartItem.getItemName());
    }

    cartItemAdapter.updateCartList(cartList);

    Log.d("loadItemsInCart", "Load Items In Cart is triggered");
}
```

`CartItemAdapter.java`

```
public class CartItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CartItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private final ArrayList<CartItem> cartItems;

    public CartItemAdapter(ArrayList<CartItem> cartItems) {
        this.cartItems = cartItems;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView itemCode, itemName, quantity, price;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            this.itemCode = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_code);
            this.itemName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            this.quantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
            this.price = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
        View cartListItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.add_to_cart_item, parent, false);
        return new CartItemAdapter.ViewHolder(cartListItem);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.itemCode.setText(cartItems.get(position).getItemCode());
        holder.itemName.setText(cartItems.get(position).getItemName());
        holder.quantity.setText(cartItems.get(position).getQuantity().toString());
        holder.price.setText(cartItems.get(position).getTotalAmount().toString());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return cartItems.size();
    }

    @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
    public void updateCartList(ArrayList<CartItem> cartList) {
        cartItems.clear();
        this.cartItems.addAll(cartList);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

The error message that I get is as below

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void app.project.jsml_sales_app.adapters.CartItemAdapter.updateCartList(java.util.ArrayList)' on a null object reference
    at app.project.jsml_sales_app.activities.fragments.CartFragment.loadItemsInCart(CartFragment.java:128)
    at app.project.jsml_sales_app.activities.NewSaleActivity$1.onTabSelected(NewSaleActivity.java:78)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.dispatchTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1993)
    at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:1986)
```

Comment: Exception shows your adapter is null. It might happens when your fragment has been disposed from memory - it might happen with one of implementation of ```PagerAdapter```. Although it usually happens when you left this tab, but not when you just entered it. Double check fragments instantiation in this adapter. Also please take a look on ```DiffUtil``` usage, it a right way to submit a new data into ```RecyclerView``` https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/paging/AsyncPagedListDiffer. Here is also a codelab for reference https://cutt.ly/e3g3FYd

Comment: Thanks @Gleichmut, will look into it or try find another way to do this